# What does [attr.something] in a selector mean in Angular?

Tags: angular

Hi I have just a question that I couldn't find so far.

What does the `[attr.colspan]` mean -> specifically the `attr.` in Angular? It might be very basic, but I never faced it before.

Here is a code example:

```
<td [attr.colspan]="(jobPositionAttributesModal$ | async).length + 2 [class.inbetween]="inbetween">
```

Hope you can help me and give me some advice. Thank you.

Comment: please read official doc  : https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#html-attribute-vs-dom-property

Answer (score 1):

You need this to dynamically assign native attributes. You are assigning the `colspan` attribute of the `td` element here.